# How can I implement the instruction jrlti (jump-register if less than immediate) in the MIPS one cycle datapath?

Tags: mips, cpu-architecture

I have trouble implementing the instruction jrlti. I don't have the right to modify the ALU so it must remain intact.

Here is how the instruction is defined:

[rs] < SignImm ? PC = [rt] : PC = PC + 4

Where is the comparison [rs] < SignImm handled in the mips one-cycle datapath? Do I use the ALU to handle it, if so how? What are the part that I have to add.

[image: This is the standard datapath I'm using]

[image: This is what I tried to do]

How can I do PC = [rt] and than PC = PC + 4 Please correct me on any false assumption I may have made while trying to implement the instruction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Obviously, if you use the ALU to make the comparison, you cannot use it for anything else as you are on a single cycle architecture, and you must find another path.

Comparison is done between SrcA (RD1) and Imm16. So the register to write to PC in order to jump is in RD2.

There is presently **no path** between RD2 and PC. The only pathes from RD2 lead to the memory or the input of ALU. So you must add a path between RD2 and PC.

There are several ways to do that but the simpler is to add a multiplexer just after PCBranch and that will drive to PC either the address computed for branches or the register RD2 for this new instruction. In both situations, the same signal (the output of ALU comparison) is used to control which value is written to PC.

Modifications must also be done on the control unit with an additional signal to control this multiplexer.